# How can a hypothesis test be done for means of two groups?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have managed to arrive to the following two tables, 
can a hypothesis test be used to test the significant difference between the means?

**EDIT:** I am watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NkGvw18zlGQ, to see if I can figure this out, however, any ideas or help is appreciated.

**EDIT 2**, my hand calculation with calculator:

```
Mean = 3.5 – 3.05
Square root: 0.7744 + 0.715716
N = 40
= 0.7744 / 40 = 0.01936
= 0.715716 / 40 = 0.0178929
= 0.19301010336
0.45 / 0.19301010336 = 2.33
```

Comment: This seems correct to me. You will obtain a p-value of $0.01981$. Depending on what significance level you at testing at, you might reject or fail to reject the $H_0$. Mostly $\alpha=5\%$ is used, and in this case you will reject $H_0$ then :) @AlixBlaine

Comment: @Stochastic, I just read in a book, that one can do "paired observation", maybe that's wrong now. I am still kind of failing to understand, if my choice is correct. I have an alpha = 0.05, confidence interval at 95%.

Comment: For paired observations the following is important to note: "Paired data arise when two of the same measurements are taken from the same subject, but under different experimental conditions." So it depends on your data. Paired tests are often used in biostatistics to test whether a medical treatment has had a significant effect on a patient - there will be a treatment group and a control group, but both groups come from the same subject still. Does this make more sense?

Comment: The participants were all the same people  in the same group, total 40. Towards the end of my questionnaire, they were presented with two rating scales and questions, "how would you rate the web experience of product x?" and "how would you rate the mobile experience of product x?", x = the same product, but can be access across platforms. Do you get the picture now, @Stochastic.?

Comment: So, the tables above represents the means and standard deviations of the ratings, one for ratings given for web experience and the other mobile experience.

Comment: Alix, you have accepted a wrong answer. I posted in the chat why z-testing is at least dicey if not outright wrong in this situation of not knowing the population variances. Further, you’re data are on a Likert scale, which has better methods of analysis than z- and t-testing. I’m not going to tell you to accept Demetri’s, but please do consider those comments about testing Likert data.

Comment: @Dave, thanks for your response. But, this isn't about the Likert Scales themselves, it is about comparing the scores that same users gave to two different questions. My professor, told me, that for an independent study like this, I should consider using a Hypothesis test, not a Chi-square test. So, the assumption was Z or T, and T seemed to make sense for a "pair observable" method.

Comment: **Z** seemed to make sense, given the circumstances.

Comment: A chi-squares test *is* a hypothesis test. Now why would you prefer z over t?

Comment: @Dave, chi-square test is more commonly used to compare association between two variables of data.

Comment: You have two variables: group and answer. Further, hypothesis tests can be of much more than means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a **z-test** here to test for the difference between the two means.
Here is some notes from my undergrad years on tests for the difference of means between two groups.

Sampling distribution: $\bar{X}_1-\bar{X}_2 \sim \operatorname{N}\left(\mu_1-\mu_2, \frac{s_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{s_2^2}{n_2}\right)$

$$Z=\frac{\bar{X}_1-\bar{X}_2-(\mu_1-\mu_2)}{\sqrt{\frac{s_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{s_2^2}{n_2}}} \sim \operatorname{N}(0,1)$$

$(1-\alpha)100\% \operatorname{Confidence interval}:$
$$\left(\bar{x}_1-\bar{x}_2-Z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{s_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{s_2^2}{n_2}}; \bar{x}_1-\bar{x}_2+Z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{s_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{s_2^2}{n_2}}\right)$$

#### Hypothesis testing

$z=\frac{\bar{x}_1-\bar{x}_2}{\sqrt{\frac{s_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{s_2^2}{n_2}}}$

$H_0: \mu_1=\mu_2$ 
$H_1: \mu_1 \neq \mu_2$

if $\alpha$ is specified, reject $H_0$ if $\mid{z} \mid >Z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}$

#### EDIT

The **chi-square test** might be more applicable depending on what the data looks like as beautifully illustrated in the example by @DemetriPananos

Comment: What pairing do you see?

Comment: I don't see anything in the OP to indicate that the two groups of 40 values each are paired. (overlapped with Dave)

Comment: I might be confused sorry, I should've double checked before I gave an answer. We are looking for a two sample t test here right? @Dave

Comment: Stochastic, thanks for your response. I am currently not using any programming languages, I am using SPSS and Excel. But, I am kind of confused, of which T-test I shall use, or Hypothesis test. The versions, are independent i.e. they differ, think desktop and mobile. So, I have rating from 1-5 from 40 participants. Now, I could use a third variable `diff` between A & B. and then do more calculations, but that takes too long time. So now I have these two tables.

Comment: Hi @AlixBlaine I edited my answer and have include some notes form my undergrad years. There is an excel command you can use as well.

Comment: @Stochastic, thanks again. I will investigate this further tomorrow. As it gives good ground I think. Thanks a lot. It is getting late now. But, feel free to update your answer, if You come up with something.

Comment: @Stochastic, is this a two-tailed z-test?

Comment: I would like to think so :) @AlixBlaine

Comment: @Stochastic, does my calculation make sense? I am not sure, does it seem correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108625/discussion-between-stochastic-and-alix-blaine).

Answer (score 2):

Since your data is from a Likert Scale, a typical t-test *may* be ok to do but there are some better approaches.

In particular, retaining the raw data and creating a 2x5 contingency table (columns are response values, rows are versions) is likely the easiest approach provided you are only interested in differences between versions rather than specific hypotheses (e.g. trends in responses between two groups, or responses in relation to some reference category).

#### Why I Don't Think A T Test Is Approproate

A t-test is capable of telling you if the differences of the means between groups is larger than would be expected under the null.  But, I don't think that is what you're after.  Consider the following example

```
     answer
group  1  2  3  4  5
    A 15  0  0  0 15
    B  1  9  7 10  3
```

30 people in each group (enough to use the z test, according to some people).  Note that the distribution of scores is very different.  Version A is very polarizing, where as version B is fairly homogeneous.

Let's take a peak at the statistics, as you show us

```
  group `mean(answer)` `sd(answer)`     n
  <fct>          <dbl>        <dbl> <int>
1 A               3            2.03    30
2 B               3.17         1.09    30
```

A t-test results in a p-value of 0.69; we would fail to reject the null that the means are different.  But, there is clearly a difference between groups that the mean does not capture!  The chi-square test does capture this difference and detects that the response distribution is different between groups A and B, resulting in a p-value < 0.001.

Without seeing the raw data, I can't conclude the t-test is the right way to go. Can you include the data?  If not, then I have to remain quite firm that the t-test should not be used.

Comment: Differences between Desktop experience and Mobile experience, which participants rated. I was told, that an hypothesis test can be used here. But, I know, that there do exist a few different Hypothesis T-tests.

Comment: Then my recommendation is the chi-square test.  This test should test the null that the responses on your Likert scale are independent of version (be it desktop or mobile).

Comment: H0 = there's not an average significant difference between web and mobile? 
H1 = there's an average significant difference between web and mobile? 

Hypothesis test, not a chi-squared test.

Comment: The chi-squared test *is a hypothesis test*.  The null would be H0 : the response frequencies in each of the 5 categories do not depend on what variant of the platform users used.  HA: The response frequencies *do* depend on which variant users used.  The average in a Liker scale doesn't really tell you the whole story.  If half my users rate their experience as a 5 and the others a 1, then my average is 3 even though nobody entered a 3.

Comment: I know, but, that's not the one that is supposed to be used here. This is similar, to the example in the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NkGvw18zlGQ, but I am confused by: `z` and then `t` .. tests

Comment: Is this a homework question?  If it is, then please ignore my answer and add the `self study` tag to your question.

Comment: This is NOT homework, this is a study I am doing. Talked with a person today, that was in a hurry and he looked at my calculations for these tables, and told me that this must be done with Hypothesis test, z or t. But, I am confused to which I shall, use. I am unable to find good details.

Comment: I think the person you spoke with is mistaken.  You're more than welcome to use the t-test.  Under certain conditions, it should reject the null when it is false.  From what you've told me, I think the chi-squared test is better.  If you instead want to perform the t-test, user Stochastic has provided those details.

Comment: Use t: $n_1 < 30$ and/or $n_2 < 30$, data normal, samples independent and $σ_1 = σ_2 = σ$ is unknown.

Use z: $n_1 ≥ 30$, $n_2 ≥ 30$, and both $σ_1$ and $ σ_2$ unknown

Comment: @Stochastic, so I should use both **t**-test and **z**-test?

Comment: I would use the z one in this case, because it suits your data. Your variances of the populations are not known, I believe. Those standard deviations that you have in the table, I assume they are calculated from the sample? You can use the t-test if your population variances are known and when they are equal - this is one of the binding assumptions of the t-test @AlixBlaine

Comment: Before continuing, I would read my edit demonstrating why the t-test is perhaps not the right thing to do.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jo4hhzonpRg

Comment: This actually makes a lot more sense now, very nice way to illustrate it!